# JSON error: Expecting 'STRING'

Tags: json

```
[
    {
        votes: "3449",
        title: "The Martian | Official Trailer [HD] | 20th Century FOX",
        post_url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ue4PCI0NamI",
        inner_url: "https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/390vcp/the_martian_official_trailer_hd_20th_century_fox/"
    },
    {
        votes: "4582",
        title: "The Easter Island heads have detailed bodies",
        post_url: "http://imgur.com/a/vDFzS",
        inner_url: "https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/390cfz/the_easter_island_heads_have_detailed_bodies/"
    }
]
```

There's a problem in line 2, but I don't see anything wrong with my json above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check a JSON using tools like http://jsonlint.com/.

In your case, the problem is that you are not putting your key names in quotes. Unlike Javascript, JSON requires it (and unlike JavaScript, JSON only allows double quotes around keys and strings, not single quotes).

Your JSON would look like this:

```
[
    {
        "votes": "3449",
        "title": "The Martian | Official Trailer [HD] | 20th Century FOX",
        "post_url": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ue4PCI0NamI",
        "inner_url": "https://www.reddit.com/r/movies/comments/390vcp/the_martian_official_trailer_hd_20th_century_fox/"
    },
    {
        "votes": "4582",
        "title": "The Easter Island heads have detailed bodies",
        "post_url": "http://imgur.com/a/vDFzS",
        "inner_url": "https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/390cfz/the_easter_island_heads_have_detailed_bodies/"
    }
]
```

Comment: @ Elton: You might also consider putting your non-string values, like `3449`, *not* in quotes so they are transferred as numbers, not strings.